# Getting value for webpage - rewriting code so no sql injection

Tags: vb.net, parameters

I'm trying to rewrite my code to prevent vulnerability to SQL Injection.  I see code for inserting or updating tables, but not for just getting a value.  Here is the code I have that is vulnerable:

```
 'Get network login name (name only)
    split = windowsLoginName.Split("\".ToCharArray)
    vname = split(1)

    'Get employeeid from table that matches login name 
    cmde.CommandText = "SELECT EmployeeID FROM tblEmployees where login = '" & vname & "'"
    cmde.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmde.Connection = sqlConnection

    sqlConnection.Open()

    'employeeid
    rve = cmde.ExecuteScalar()

    sqlConnection.Close()
```

I started rewriting the code and this is what I have so far:

```
sql1 = "Select EmployeeID from tblEmployees where login = @loginname"
cmde = new sqlcommand(sql1)
```

This is where I'm stuck:

```
cmde.parameters.????("@loginname", vname)
cmde.ExecuteReader()
```

I'm not adding or updating or inserting - I just want the value to appear on my webpage.  What is the code for this?  And is the rest of the code correct?  Thanks in advance!

****Continued...
After help, I came up with this code but I'm getting an error - ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.  I'm confused.  Here's the code:

```
Dim windowsLoginName As System.String = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name   'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

    Dim split As String() = Nothing
    Dim vname As String

    Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=WillSQL\ict2;Initial Catalog=TimeSQL;Integrated Security=SSPI")
    Dim sqlemp As String
    Dim cmde As New SqlCommand
    Dim rve As Object
 'Get network login name (name only)
    split = windowsLoginName.Split("\".ToCharArray)
    vname = split(1)

    'Get employeeid from table that matches login name 

    sqlConnection.Open()
    sqlemp = "SELECT EmployeeID FROM tblEmployees where login = @loginname"
    cmde = New SqlCommand(sqlemp)
    cmde.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loginname", vname)
    rve = cmde.ExecuteReader()
    sqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Huh? You're adding a parameter.  That's not different from any other code that uses parameters.

Comment: cmde.parameters.AddWithValue("@loginname", vname) should do it.

Comment: Thanks Norbert!  Now, I'm getting an error - ExecuteReader:  Connection property has not been initialized.  I'll edit the post so you can see the code.

Comment: You need to tie the command and connection together; the example at [SqlCommand.ExecuteReader Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows an easy way. Also, you may want to avoid using variable names which are the same as class names (sqlConnection in your code) as it can make it awkward to debug some things. P.P.S `.AddWithValue` will come back to bite you some day, it is more reliable to use something more like `.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@loginname", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = vname})`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew!  I think I'm getting somewhere.  I'm opening a new post related to this.